# Load data from function to state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have function which load all data from API. I would like to use that function to pass that data to array. But i cannot figured out how to do that.

I have already tried to put that function inside of state of my array, because I do not know how to use that function

```
function getRoles {
    const url = 'URLTOENDPOINT'
    fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, {
        method: "GET",
    })
    .then(response => {
        Object.keys(response.json.value).forEach(function (key) {
            var object = response.json.value[key];
            names.push(object.Name);
        })
    });
    return names;
}
```

Simply i want to load data from `getRoles` function to this array inside state:

```
class MultipleSelect extends React.Component {
    state = {
      name: [
        'Oliver Hansen',
        'Van Henry',
        'April Tucker'
      ]
    };

...
```

Expected result should be MultipleSelect with default data loaded from API.

Any ideas how to use that function or what should be improved?

Comment: You can call the API in the component lifecycle (In there save your state) or you can store your data in a state manager like redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.setState({name:getRoles()})
 }
```

you can try this way also function return directly set it to state variable

```
class MultipleSelect extends React.Component {
   state = {
     name: [
      'Oliver Hansen',
      'Van Henry',
      'April Tucker'
  ]
};

 getRoles() {
  const url = 'URLTOENDPOINT'
  var names
  fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, {
  method: "GET",
  })
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then((res) => {
   console.log(res)
  names = res.value.map((data)=>(data.Name))
 })
 return names;
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({name:this.getRoles()})
 }
}
```

Comment: Where to put this? inside the class?

Comment: If i put it in the class i have to declare the function here too? Because the function is declared above the class declaration now

Comment: you can make as service file or something else but you have to call function any way

Comment: you can keep inside the class but you have to follow the react rules for that to use fucntion inside the class

Comment: Wow! Really helpful thank you. But the data appears only when i click on that input, is that way to display them after refresh?

Comment: onload this componentDidMount will set the data to the states name variable ,if you want after that also new data then you have to call new fucntion with same api on onclick event or onchange event of reactjs

Comment: I would like to have that data from API there instead of harcoded `name` array

Comment: getRoles() when returns array that sets the new array to the state name variable by componentDidMount
https://repl.it/repls/GivingCuddlyDevices ,go to this link and see

Comment: But i have something like this now? If i follow your code, or not?

Comment: I already find the problem, but not able to solve that. I have found that when the data is hardcoded in getRoles function everything is okay, but when I make a API call the data does not appear, just after click on input

Comment: are you getting response in array from the api or not

Comment: The final data i am working with are array, but response is represented in json, As you can see in my function declaration

Comment: attach screenshot of your response ,then i can suggest something to you

Comment: To edit my previous answer i can load them into array, they are there, but do not appear while i refresh site, just when i do some action on input

Answer (score 0):

Addition to my comment:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      `https://xxx`,
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(val=> {
        this.setState({ ... });
      });
  }
```